# How to satisfy dependencies for Apache POI on Android?

Tags: android, apache-poi, stax

There are many posts about reading .docx files with Apache POI on Android. I write Java program, which do it and want move it Android platform. But XWPFDocument requires xmlbeans.jar, and xmlbeans.jar requires stax-api.jar. And **Stax API can not be added to android app**, because it tries to extends javax.* namespace, which is not allowed.

So question is: how can I satisfy dependencies for Apache POI on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: There is now https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android which is actively maintained and allows at least the core functionality of Apache POI to be used on Android.

Some limitations apply, mostly Java AWT related stuff where Android does not provide the related implementation.

The project also provides a sample-application which shows how some of the functionality can be used.

---

Outdated Content:

> There are now at least two projects which try to solve most of the
> problems when using Apache POI on Android. Only some methods when
> handling images will still fail because Apache POI uses stuff form
> java.awt which Android does not have.
>
> Take a look at
>
> 1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx
> 2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (mainted by me)
>
> The first one is currently based on POI 3.12, whereas the second can
> be re-compiled with newer versions of POI more easily.

Answer (score -1):

Long investigation shown, it is **not possible to use Apache POI on Android** platform for editing .docx files.

Comment: That's not correct, plenty of people have done so, see various posts here for details. The XML based file formats look much trickier than the older binary ones though

Comment: Could you please point me on any working solution? All I saw is "Try Apache POI" without concrete recipe. Do you know answere to this exact question? Or could you point me to someone, who know?

Comment: There's [lots of Apache POI + Android questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-poi+android), some of those indicate solutions for the binary formats. I don't have an Android device, so I haven't tried anything of late

Comment: Yes, lots of questions. No answer, pointing on solution for concrete question. Same like your 2 comments, no offence.

Comment: Please give https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android a try, it should allow at least basic functionality to be used fairly easily.

Comment: Thank @centic The need is long gone, but I hope your library would actually solve the issue for next wave of developers.